# Prestashop product ID start from

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there a way to make PrestaShop assign IDs to products starting from a given number? For example, start assigning from '500000'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your product table AUTO INCREMENT number.

so do this: `ALTER TABLE`table_name`AUTO_INCREMENT=500000`

Comment: It should. I have made same with orders when migrate from OLD to new shop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `BO > Advanced parameters > CSV Import` with the option `Force all ID numbers` enabled. In your csv file give the ids you want for the products.